# Função para o tratamento todos os parâmetros tipo data em um Objeto multilevel com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando criar uma função que trabalhe sobre todos os parametros de um objeto JSON para procurar campos data e manipular os mesmos. Basicamente o objeto que eu posso receber é algo do tipo:

```
{
  idPedido:1,
  dataCriado: "/Date(1454637600000-0200)/",
  cliente: "Nome do Cliente",
  pagamento:[
    {
      idPgto:1,
      valor: 100.00,
      tipoPgto:"dinheiro",
      dataVenc:"/Date(1454637600000-0200)/"
    },
    {
      idPgto:2,
      valor: 100.00,
      tipoPgto:"cartão",
      dataVenc:"/Date(1454657600000-0200)/"
    }
  ],
  produtos:[
    {
      idProduto:1,
      descricao:"bola",
      valor:200.00
    }
  ]
}
```

Meu problema é que podem existir inúmeras variantes que contenham esse formato de data (infelizmente o webservice que estou sendo obrigado a trabalhar só me manda isso dessa forma...)

Preciso saber como eu posso fazer uma função que eu consiga aplicar sobre todos os parâmetros que existam dentro do JSON, independente do nível do mesmo. hoje a função que eu estou utilizando é esta:

```
function corrigeData(d) {
  if(d.indexOf('Date('){
    d = d.replace(/\/Date\(/g, '').replace(/\)\//g, '');
    d = new Date(d);
  };
  return d;
}
```

O problema é que eu tenho que pegar e saber onde eu provavelmente vou encontrar o campo data. Mas se por acaso mudarem alguma coisa no meu escopo no backend, eu vou ter que voltar e implementar isso também, o que é desnecessário com uma função recursiva.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Sem saber que versões de formatos vais receber é dificil prever. Dúvidas: - porque não usas o parametro `-xxxx` dessa data? - sabes se pelo menos esse webservice vai sempre mandar timestamps? nesse caso podias usar somente `.match(/\d{13}/)` e serve para todos os casos onde houver um timestamp se as datas são modernas.

Comment: sim, o webservice sei vai mandar esse formato de data timestamps mas em campos diferentes.. ao invés de eu fazer um tratamento campo por campo, eu preferiria que onde ele bater um `param.indexOf('Date(')` ele rodar a função naquele parametro, atualizando o mesmo.

Comment: além disso, a função **corrigeData()** acima já faz a substituição que eu quero, só preciso saber como rodar ela em todos os parametros independente do nível dentro do JSON

Comment: Usa os 13 dígitos que são timestamp dando um new Date nele você já sabe que tem a data. E tenta mapear os formatos, e invalidar caso venha algo muito fora do comum. O WebService deveria dar suporte para as datas de forma concisa.

Comment: Leandro, seria algo assim? -> https://jsfiddle.net/j3Lquh7j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um função recursiva:

```js
var jsonObj = {
  idPedido:1,
  dataCriado: "/Date(1454637600000-0200)/",
  cliente: "Nome do Cliente",
  pagamento:[
    {
      idPgto:1,
      valor: 100.00,
      tipoPgto:"dinheiro",
      dataVenc:"/Date(1454637600000-0200)/"
    },
    {
      idPgto:2,
      valor: 100.00,
      tipoPgto:"cartão",
      dataVenc:"/Date(1454657600000-0200)/"
    }
  ],
  produtos:[
    {
      idProduto:1,
      descricao:"bola",
      valor:200.00
    }
  ]
};

function corrigeData(d) {
 d = d.replace(/\/Date\(/g, '').replace(/\)\//g, '');
 d = new Date(d);
 return d;
};

function applyToDateFields(object, fn) {
 for (var i in object) {
  var item = object[i];
  var type = typeof item;
  
  if (type === 'string' && item.indexOf('/Date(') !== -1) {
   object[i] = fn(object[i]);
  }
  else if (type === 'object') {
   applyToDateFields(item, fn);
  }
 }
};

applyToDateFields(jsonObj, corrigeData);

console.log(jsonObj);
document.write(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

`corrigeData` será aplicada a todos os campos `/Date(`, não importa em que nível de aninhamento eles estejam. Contudo note que sua `corrigeData` tem algum problema no processamento já ela retorna "Invalid date" sempre, como essa não era a sua pergunta eu não debuguei para ver o erro.

Comment: sim eu vi aqui que está com um erro, é por causa do tipo do timezone... mas já achei como resolver, obrigado parceiro!

Answer (score 1):

Para verificares os campos dentro de um objeto de profundidade desconhecida tens de utilizar uma função recursiva. Algo assim:

```
var regex = /Date\(([^\)]+)\)/;
var timestamp = /(\d{12,13})/

function converterData(obj, regex) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        if (obj[key] instanceof Object) converterData(obj[key], regex);
        else if (typeof obj[key] == 'string' && obj[key].match(regex)) {
            var ts = parseInt(obj[key].match(timestamp)[0], 10);
            obj[key] = new Date(ts);
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
var saida = converterData(entrada, regex);
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/j3Lquh7j/